# Dynamic horizontal scroller

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to make this horizontal side scrolling side that moves to different elements depending on the button click.

https://codepen.io/mikayp-the-styleful/pen/eYYMRXp

The concerns are two things. One is the CSS. Looks like the elements arent moving based on their  transform: translateX when I click the 'about' button. Am I missing something there?

The bigger problem is the JS. I believe this code is really inefficient. Is there a way I can restructure it so I don't have to make a function on each button click but instead one function that just moves the screen around to the specific sections? I've seen similar with traditional vertical sites but not horizontal.

```
function toAbout(){
    var welcome = document.querySelector('.welcome');
    var about = document.querySelector('.about');
    var professional = document.querySelector('.professional');
    var funStuff = document.querySelector('.fun-stuff');
    var blog = document.querySelector('.blog');
    var contact = document.querySelector('.contact');


    about.className += " slide-zero";
    professional.className += " slide-plus-100";
    welcome.className += " slide-plus-200";
    funStuff.className += " slide-plus-300";
    blog.className += " slide-plus-400";
    contact.className += " slide-plus-500";

};
```